# What JAR Version has XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and What is its value?

Tags: java, xml

I inherited some code. I am missing `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD` in my Java JRE 7 rt.jar, so the code does not compile.

What JAR is this in and what is its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.0.1.el7_2.x86_64 installed. Using jd-gui, I can confirm that the static variable you are looking for is both present and in the rt.jar. For reference, the location of the jar on my machine is java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.0.1.el7_2.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar.

[image]

[Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxp-api/1.4.2)  is the jar for jax api, which also contains the needed class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As far as what value it is, here is what the documentation [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD):

> Value: a list of protocols separated by comma. A protocol is the scheme portion of a URI, or in the case of the JAR protocol, "jar" plus the scheme portion separated by colon. A scheme is defined as:
>
> scheme = alpha *( alpha | digit | "+" | "-" | "." )
>    where alpha = a-z and A-Z.
>    And the JAR protocol:
>    jar[:scheme]
>    Protocols including the keyword "jar" are case-insensitive. Any whitespaces as defined by Character.isSpaceChar(char) in the value will be ignored. Examples of protocols are file, http, jar:file.

For me, running this program:

```
package sample;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("### " + XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD);
    }  
}
```

Prints out:

```
### http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
```

Comment: This was never in _Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar_? I wonder how past developers compiled.

Comment: Nope. I added _javax.xml.jaxp-api version 1.4.2_ dependency to my POM and `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD` is not in that either. The class `XMLConstants` is there but the constant `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD`is not there.

Comment: I have open JDK, and I can see it in my jar. Use jd-gui to look at your local install, see if you can find it in there. Sounds like you are having a bad import, or conflicting classes. I'll update the answer with my screenshots

Comment: Interesting, yep that's what I needed. Nice answer. I love jg-gui, the Eclipse plugin is also nice. I wonder how my rt.jar got corrupted...

Comment: @javaPlease42 I cannot say for sure, as I have never seen that happen. Just out of curiosity, is your jdk from oracle, and running on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turned out it was because the `XMLConstants` class was pulled from a JAR in an old Eclipse platform that the project depends on (javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar). Modifying the settings so that the Java library takes precedence fixed it for me.